# Why do I need this shebang?

Tags: shell-script, shebang

`perldoc perlrun` contains this example:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #! -*-perl-*-
 eval 'exec perl -x -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
     if 0;
```

But I don't understand why it might be needed.

---

For example, if my perl interpreter has been installed in `/home/user/folder/../../..`
and I use such a construct — will my script work?